# Open "Select file" dialog and send form using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, file, upload

I have a simple form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/clients" method="post">
    <input id="file" type="file" />
</form>
```

I need to invoke file upload dialog and if it was successful - send the form
(using javascipt)

Comment: "and if it was successful, send the form" the file gets uploaded by sending the form, so what you are asking doesn't make any sense

Comment: firstly I need user to choose file on his computer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/clients" method="post" id="fileForm">
    <input id="file" type="file" />
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById('file').onchange=function () {
document.getElementById('fileForm').submit();
}
</script>
```